# Cannot find name 'response'. Did you mean 'Response'

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I get this error for a nodejs code from VS code

```
var protocol = require("http");
protocol.createServer(function(request,response){
  response.writeHead(200,{'Content-type':'text/html'});
  
 }).listen(8000);
```

error I getting is:
Cannot find name 'response'. Did you mean 'Response'.
response is not bring up any properties.

Answer (score 0):

try to fix your syntax by properly defining the function like this `function(x, y) {}`. The curly braces in your code are misplaced.

E.g:

```
var protocol = require("http");
protocol.createServer(function(request,response){
  response.writeHead(200,{'Content-type':'text/html'});  
});
```

Comment: I updated the code. so on the line response.writeHead  I do not get the intellisense for writeHead .